# Nested query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

My team owns several dashboard and are considering the possibility to move to Elasticsearch in order to consolidate the software stacks. One type of common charts we expose is like "What's the pending workflow by the end of each day?". Here are some example data:

```
day workflow_id version status
20151101    1   1   In Progress
20151101    2   1   In Progress
20151102    1   2   In Progress
20151102    3   1   In Progress
20151102    4   1   In Progress
20151102    2   2   Completed
20151103    1   3   Completed
20151103    3   2   In Progress
20151104    3   3   Completed
20151105    4   2   Completed
```

Every time when something changed in the workflow, a new record is inserted, which might or might not change the status. The record with the max(version) is the most recent data for the workflow_id.

The goal is to have a chart to show what's the total number of 'In Progress' and 'Completed' workflows at the end of each day. This should only consider the record that has the largest version number until the day. This can be done in SQL with nested queries:

```
with 

snapshot_dates as 
(select distinct day from workflow),

snapshot as 
(select d.day, w.workflow_id, max(w.version) as max_version
from snapshot_dates d, workflow w
where d.day >= w.day
group by d.day, w.workflow_id
order by d.day, w.workflow_id)

select s.day, w.status, count(1) 
from workflow w join snapshot s on w.workflow_id=s.workflow_id and w.version = s.max_version
group by s.day, w.status
order by s.day, w.status;
```

Here is expected output from the query:

```
day,status,count  
20151101,In Progress,2  
20151102,Completed,1  
20151102,In Progress,3  
20151103,Completed,2  
20151103,In Progress,2  
20151104,Completed,3  
20151104,In Progress,1  
20151105,Completed,4
```

I am still new to Elasticsearch and wonder if Elasticsearch can do a similar query without using application side logic by properly define the mapping and query. More generally, what is the best practice to solve such problem using Elasticsearch?

Comment: You should use aggregation based on date.  you can check  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html this link.

Comment: You should river your data to elasticsearch. If you have a structured data, you can create a mapping, it is super easy your queries. Some times elasticsearch query crashing if the same data has different type.

Comment: The difficulty here is that there won't be a record for each work flow every day. For example, on 20151104, there is no record for work flow id 4, it should use the record on 20151102 since that's the most updated version at the time. For 20151105 though, the record on 20151105 with version 2 should be used.

Comment: I did not understand exactly. I try to explain. Create a field of date. Add record and its date and collect lots of data. And aggregate your data firstly date and after that aggregate aggregated data with workflow. or exactly opposite. Firstly aggregate workflow after that aggregate date. You can use nested aggregation for that. Sorry link is false. I change it in one minute.

Comment: Sorry again. I used wrong term. `Subaggregation` is correct one. You can find information about that https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations Nested aggregation is for nested documents. My fault.

Comment: Thanks Hkulekci. I am currently reading through the document around subagregations. I will update back if I can figure out a solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the solution using [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html), but I was stuck at one point. I discussed the same in [elasticsearch forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bucket-selector-aggregation-script-access-doc-index-field-value/35516). Following is what suggested by [Christian Dahlqvist](https://discuss.elastic.co/users/Christian_Dahlqvist/activity).

> In addition to this you also index the record into a workflow-centric
>   index with a unique identifier, e.g. workflow id, as the document id.
>   If several updates come in for the same workflow, each will result in
>   an update and the latest state will be preserved. Running aggregations
>   across this index to find the current or latest state will be
>   considerably more efficient and scalable as you only have a single
>   record per workflow and do not need to filter out documents based on
>   relationships to other documents.

So as per this suggestion, you should use `Workflow Id` as document id while indexing. And whenever there is an update for that workflow, you update new version and date using workflow id. Let's say the index name is `workflow` and index type is `workflow_status`. So mapping of this `workflow_status` type will be as follow:

```
{
    "workflow_status": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "status": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "version": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "workFlowId": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep adding/updating the documents to this index type keeping `workFlowId` as document id.

Now for showing a chart day wise, you may need to create another index type, let's say `per_day_workflow` with following mapping:

```
{
    "per_day_workflow": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },            
            "in_progress": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "completed": {
                "type": "long"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This index will hold data for each day. So you need to create a job which will run at the end of day and fetch total "In Progress" & "Completed" workflow from `workflow_status` index type using following aggregation search:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/workflow/workflow_status/_search?search_type=count

    {
        "aggs": {
            "per_status": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "status"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Response will look as follow (I ran for date 2015-11-02 on your sample data):

```
{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "per_status": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "In Progress",
                    "doc_count": 3
                },
                {
                    "key": "Completed",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

From this response you need to extract `In Progress` and `Completed` count and add them to `per_day_workflow` index type with today's' date.

Now when you need per day data for your graph, then you can fetch easily from this `per_day_workflow` index type.